How to show $\iint_R\frac{f(1,2)}{1+3u^2}\,dA=\iint_R\frac{f(2,1)}{1+3u^2}\,dA$?
$\displaystyle \text{... where }f(a,b) = \frac1{1+as^2+bu^2}\text{, and }R=\left\{(s,u)\in[0,1]\times[0,\infty)\right\}$.
According to this post $(1)$ and this post $(2)$,
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^\tfrac1{\sqrt2} \frac{\arctan\sqrt{1-2t^2}}{1+t^2} \, dt &= \frac{\pi^2}{24} \tag1 \\
\int_0^{\sqrt2} \frac{\arctan\sqrt{2-t^2}}{1+t^2} \, dt &= \frac{\pi^2}{12} \tag2
\end{align*}$$
I was thinking about whether there might be some fancy way to conclude that one integral is half the other. By expressing the $\arctan$s as integrals and respectively substituting $u_1=\dfrac t{\sqrt{1-2t^2}}$ and $u_2=\dfrac t{\sqrt{2-t^2}}$ to make the domains of integration uniform, I found that
$$I_1 = \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{du\,ds}{\left(1+3u^2\right)\left(1+s^2+\color{red}{2u^2}\right)} \stackrel{(*)}= \int_0^1 \int_0^\infty \frac{du\,ds}{\left(1+3u^2\right)\left(1+\color{red}{2s^2}+u^2\right)} = I_2$$
Expanding into partial fractions and integrating w.r.t. $u$ then $s$ is certainly doable. However, given the pseudo-symmetry of the double-integrands and the ultimate parity between their exact values, I now wonder:

Is there a simple or clever way to prove $(*)$ without explicitly evaluating both double integrals, or either $(1)$ or $(2)$?

